# Show class methods type-hinting

Tags: php, netbeans, type-hinting

I don't know how to phrase this one exactly but what I need is a way to load the type-hinting of a classes methods. Basically I have a `base` class that has a `get` function that looks like this:

```
class Base {

    /**
     * 
     * @param type $i
     * @return \i
     */
    public static function get($i) {
        // make sure it exists before creating
        $classes = get_declared_classes();
        if (!in_array($i, $classes)) {
            if (class_exists($i)) {
                return new $i();
            }
        }
        return $i;
    }
}
```

Now for an example, say I had a class called `test`:

```
class test {
    function derp() {
        echo 'derp';
    }
}
```

I'd instantiate the `test` object by something like this:

```
$test = base::get('test');
```

Now what I'd like to be able to do is as I type like this:

```
$test->
```

The methods (*Currently only derp()*) should be suggested, I've seen documents all around SO but they don't work :(

What's weird is that if I change the `@return` comment to the `test` class name then the suggestions work.

**BUT** it the classes are all not set, there could be different classes instantiated, hence why I tried `@returns \i` (*suggested by netbeans*). Is there any way to achieve this?

---

### EDIT

The reason I need the type hinting is to allow for calling methods like the following:

```
base::get('test')->derp();
```

Comment: I do not use just `new`?

Comment: @sectus How do you mean?

Comment: I mean `$test = new test;`

Comment: @sectus that was an example, What I'd be using this for is something like `base::get('test')->derp();` but to have said methods suggested.

Comment: Instead of `base::get('test')->derp();` use `(new test)->derp();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What always works is this:

```
/** @var ADDTYPEHERE $test */
$test = base::get('test');
```

What also works is this:

```
if ($test instanceof CLASS_IT_IS) {
  // completion works in here
}
```

The solution you want can never work, since your IDE (netbeans) cannot know what class you instantiated, without any hint like one of the above.